# jQuery/Javascript Delay Execution of a Function Until Several Functions Have Completed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a tricky situation. I need to delay execution of a function until several functions have completed. While the following would work in a normal situation:

```
    $.when(foo1(), foo2(), foo3()).then(function(){
        //foo4();
    });
```

My situation is a little different. I don't want the functions passed to `$.when()` to execute immediately. `foo1-3` will be executed at some point in the near future, by other methods. In other words, I want to execute `foo1-3` manually, at a time of my choosing. Only after `foo1-3` have executed (in no specific order) will `foo4` run.

My intuition told me to dig into `$.Deferred()`, but I haven't quite found what I need. Any ideas?

Comment: You meant `.then(foo4)`, right? Otherwise you're passing the value returned by `foo4()` to `.then()`...

Comment: I edited it to avoid confustion. But, yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have the `fooX` functions resolve deferreds which are passed to `$.when`.

```
var d1 = $.Deferred();
var d2 = $.Deferred();
var d3 = $.Deferred();

function foo1() {
    // do normal work, then
    d1.resolve();
}

// same for other 2 functions

$.when(d1, d2, d3).then(foo4);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/nVFnv/

Answer (score 2):

Make a scoreboard variable that counts up as each function completes, then call foo4 after each function. foo4 should exit if the score has not counted up to the correct value.

Comment: Ok. Not bad. I had that idea myself. Was looking for something more elegant. But, "by hook or crook" is certainly an option.

Comment: The answer by Matt Ball is essentially your idea, just using deferred objects instead of a scoreboard variable. Thanks!